# Dropdown menu from SELECT distinct

Tags: drop-down-menu, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to create a drop-down menu from distinct values.

```
SELECT DISTINCT RoleGroup
FROM ccf.role
```

In my Controller I am

```
var RoleGroups = db.Roles.Select(x => x.RoleGroup).Distinct();

ViewBag.RoleGroups = new SelectList(RoleGroups, "RoleGroup", "RoleGroup", null);
```

In my View I am

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RoleGroup,
    (@ViewBag.RoleGroups) as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>,
    new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

I get an error of

[image]

What is all this?

Comment: While many people fancy the usage of var, I see a lot of confusion/mistakes that would have been more obvious for yourself if you would have used IEnumerable<string> from the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is returning `IEnumerable<string>` and your `SelectList` constructor is trying to access the `RoleGroup` property of `string` (the 2nd and 3rd parameters) which does not exist. It needs to be

```
ViewBag.RoleGroups = new SelectList(RoleGroups);
```